# How to fetch the values from database in the checkbox. In this the first value is only getting ticked whether its there or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strParam = Request.QueryString["submenuid"] + "";

```
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText ="select SubMenu_id from SubmenuRec where Menu_id in ('" + strParam + "')";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds);

            for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox CheckBox1;
                    CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And one more thing i forgot to tell is that it is only taking a number of count of row.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? The wording in the title is a bit confusing

Comment: There a gridview with hyperlink. When i click the particular hyperlink it should fetch the data from row which is present in database and show all the available value for particular hyperlink in to another gridview with the checkbox.

Comment: Hyperlink Checkboxes?

Comment: the first hyperlink gridview contain menus and another checkbox gridview contain the submenus related to particular menu..